# My mouse and keyboard don't work on the desktop (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: keyboard, mouse, screen, freeze

So I installed Lutris and rebooted my laptop. To my surprise, nothing worked. I couldn't move my mouse or use shortcuts. Trackpad didn't work either. However the clock worked so the screen didn't technically freeze. I tried everything I could but couldn't fix it. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm new to Linux.

Comment: Do u have portable keyboard? Connect it to your laptop(desktop? Laptor or Desktop??)
and type something. If it works, open terminal and type `sudo dmesg` and show us the result.

I do not think Lutris jammed your Laptop(Not desktop, right?) drivers, because keyboard and trackpad requires device driver and i think there is a driver issue.

But i can not explain much cuz i cant see what is happening in your laptop.

Comment: I meant desktop as in the GUI, not the machine itself. I'm not a native English speaker, sorry. Also I don't have a portable keyboard and can't buy one because of the quarantine.

Comment: What is your machine? Desktop or Laptop?

Comment: Yes, I have a laptop.

Comment: I bought an USB keyboard via e-shop but it only works the same as my normal keyboard, i.e only in the recovery mode, I can't open the terminal.